# Animate div container when adding new element to a list

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic list of il inside a div.

The actual behavior is that when I add new elements to list, the div change the height suddenly and that's not so sexy.

```
<div class="contner">
   <div class="toggle-area">
     input + dynamic list
   </div>
</div>
```

And here's the **CSS**:

```
.contner {
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
 min-height: 242px;
 width: 604px;
 padding-top:10px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 margin: 40px auto;
 padding-bottom: 12px;
-moz-transition: 0.3s;
-ms-transition: 0.3s;
-o-transition: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;

}
```

I have tried `transition` but not working

Comment: @AhsN we don't need to specify all, by default it's all ... so specifying `0.3s` is enough

Comment: you cannot have a transtion of height to auto value

Comment: @TemaniAfif I just tested it, you are right, thnx